# Laplace inverse of given question

Tags: inverse-laplace

$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{2 s - 1}{s^{4} + s^{2} + 1}\right)=~~?$$

I have done the $~\dfrac{2s}{s^4+s^2+1}~$.

But what to do with the $~\dfrac{1}{s^4+s^2+1}~$ ?

I don't get any idea after decomposition.

Comment: Hint: factor the denominator.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

$$s^4+s^2+1=(s^2+1)^2-s^2=(s^2-s+1)(s^2+s+1)$$

$$\dfrac{2s}{s^4+s^2+1}=\dfrac{(s^2+s+1)-(s^2-s+1)}{(s^2-s+1)(s^2+s+1)}=?$$

Use 
$$L(e^{at}\sin bt)=\dfrac b{(s-a)^2+b^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

[emathhelp](https://www.emathhelp.net/calculators/differential-equations/inverse-laplace-transform-calculator/?f=%282s-1%29%2F%28s%5E4%2Bs%5E2%2B1%29) gives,

$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{s^{4} + s^{2} + 1}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3} \left(- e^{t} \cos{\left(\frac{\sqrt{3} t}{2} + \frac{\pi}{6} \right)} + \sin{\left(\frac{\sqrt{3} t}{2} + \frac{\pi}{3} \right)}\right) e^{- \frac{t}{2}}$$and
$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{2 s}{s^{4} + s^{2} + 1}\right)=\frac{4}{3} \sqrt{3} \sin{\left(\frac{\sqrt{3} t}{2} \right)} \sinh{\left(\frac{t}{2} \right)}$$
Hence
$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{2 s - 1}{s^{4} + s^{2} + 1}\right)=\left(e^{t} \sin{\left(\frac{\sqrt{3} t}{2} + \frac{\pi}{6} \right)} - \frac{5}{6} \sqrt{3} \sin{\left(\frac{\sqrt{3} t}{2} \right)} - \frac{1}{2} \cos{\left(\frac{\sqrt{3} t}{2} \right)}\right) e^{- \frac{t}{2}}$$